# How to give forEach definition

Tags: javascript, refactoring

I'm brand new to coding, but decided to give it a shot just to make a fun little bot for a Discord server to surprise my friends, but I'm having a bit of an issue with refactoring in Visual Code Studio - for some reason, my forEach code isn't working all of a sudden, and I can't seem to figure out why or how to fix it,
here's the error I'm getting whenever I try to run it

> files.forEach(file => {
>             ^
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

and here's the section of code I'm using

```
fs.readdir("./events/", (err, files) => {
files.forEach(file => {
    const eventHandler = require('./events/message.js')
    const eventmessage = file.split(".")[0]
    client.on(eventmessage, (...args) => eventHandler(client,...args))
})
```

Like I said, I'm new at coding, and have largely been following online guides, but I've tried a few things, such as removing it, restarting the program, rewriting it in a different window to see that does anything, reinstalling what I'm using in the code, and so on

I'm probably being an absolute idiot and missing some piece but I'm totally baffled so any guidance (or a different way to refactor!) would help!

Thank you in advance!

Note: I am largely following this guide if that helps any!
https://thomlom.dev/create-a-discord-bot-under-15-minutes/

**EDIT:** Here's a coded copy of what I've been following, as far as I can see my code is basically exactly the same
https://github.com/thomlom/discord-bot-example

Comment: this TypeError means that files is not a valid array you can iterate on. it seems to me the path in your `readdir()` method is incorrect. it should be `"./events"`

Comment: I've given it a little tweak to try that and it's still fighting with me, but thank you! I'll give it a try in a different file to see if it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot to create the `events` folder, because I got the same error when the folder doesn't exist.

Try to follow this part of the tutorial again

```
To modularize our code, we will create an events folder. This folder will contain .js files whose name will match the different events name discord.js listens to:

Create an events folder.
In this folder, create three files: ready.js, message.js and guildMemberAdd.js.
```

Comment: I've got an events folder, and I've double check in both where I've saved it and the file that I've got it just incase, but still no luck - I'll copy and paste it into a new file under a different name and see if that helps though! Thanks!

Comment: Nope, no luck so far - downloaded the example bot to make sure I wasn't thinking I'd done something and forgotten but folder is definitely there - thanks anyway though!

Comment: Do you have this code on a repository (github, gitlab) ? just to clone it and see what is happening, maybe could be your OS.  Are you in window, mac or linux ?

Comment: Just set one up there - hopefully it should work, but if not just yell at me and I'll fix it! https://github.com/Plantriarchy/TreeBot-Test

Comment: Did u push the code? or maybe u created a private repo, make sure that is public, so I can see the code

Comment: Ay,e sorry, my bad! Brain was half asleep! Should be working now! https://github.com/Plantriarchy/TreeBot-Test

Comment: Hey I have seen that you are doing something like this:

`fs.readdir("./event/", (err, files) => {`

Try to replace with
`fs.readdir("./events", (err, files) => {`

And also, you have some typos, like: `message.js.js` => `message.js` 
`/events/ready.js.js` => `/events/ready.js`

Let me know if now is working, with these modifications

Comment: I've updated it as you said, but I'm afraid it's still giving me the same error? Sorry!

Comment: Hey !  I just checked the code and you are missing the `s` `./event` => `./events`

Comment: Sorry to ask, but is there anywhere in particular I'm supposed to add that line? I've tried a few different combos and it still doesn't seem to be working?

Comment: I just pull the code, and now is not throwing the `TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined`.

Comment: Huh, weirdly if I pull it from GitHub the issue is fixed? Thanks for all your help by the way! Sorry for all the hassle!